# Does it anti-pattern to change state parameter in render?

Tags: reactjs

I need to make simple toggle animation, if state in component was changed. But I don't want to show this animation each time when react calls component render. I found a way how to do it, but I don't like that I need to change state variable directly without setState and make it in render. Also I don't like idea to generate new key each time on animation. I think it it anti-pattern. How can I achieve same result but with different way?

```
onClick() {
    if(this.props.items.length>=5) {
        this.setState({
            toggleWarning: true
        });

    }else {
        this.props.onStepAdd();
    }
}

render() {
    let toggle = "";
    let toggleKey = null;
    if(this.state.toggleWarning) {
        toggle = " "+style.toggleMsg;
        toggleKey = {key:Math.random()};
        this.state.toggleWarning = false;
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Add New</h1>
            <div>
                <Button
                    onClick={this.onClick}
                    label="Add Step"
                />
            </div>
            <div
                className={style.noteMsg + toggle}
                {...toggleKey} >
                <h3>Note: You can create only up to 5 steps for form wizard</h3>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: Why aren't you using `setState`?  And why do you need to randomize the `key` when there is only one item?

Comment: It is antipattern to directly mutate state outside of the `setState` function. If you shared your animation code then maybe we could answer better. I suspect you'd want your animation code to have a callback that when complete calls some toggleWarning callback to toggle your state value back to false.

Answer (score 1):

not sure I understand the objective, but if you want to add a class after a click and then remove the class after some time:

```
previousTimeout = undefined
onClick = () => {
  if(this.props.items.length>=5) {
    this.setState({toggleWarning: true});
    clearTimeout(this.previousTimeout);
    this.previousTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState({toggleWarning: false})
    }, 500);
}

render() {
  ...className={style.noteMsg + this.state.toggleWarning ? ' '+style.toggleMsg : ''}
}
```